# Can i get the value of Minimum(Maximum) Processor state

Tags: c#, windows-7

Under Win7, open `Control Panel -> Power Options -> Advanced Settings->Processor power management`.

you can see Minimum Processor state, Maximum Processor state.
I want to get the value of Processor state by C#.for example 5%,100%.
I use the command "powercfg" in c#,i noly can get the value of "monitor-timeout-ac" and so on.
I can not get the value of Processor
state.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to dllimport powrprof.dll, and use ReadProcessorPwrScheme API, then access the processorPolicyInfoAc.DemotePercent and ProcessorPolicyInfoAc.PromotePercent

See the code bellow. Not tested but it will show you the way (I use this code to get DynamicThrottle information and it works).

```
    struct PROCESSOR_POWER_POLICY_INFO
        {
            public uint TimeCheck;
            public uint DemoteLimit;
            public uint PromoteLimit;
            public byte DemotePercent;
            public byte PromotePercent;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
            public byte[] Spare;
            public uint AllowBits;
        }

        struct PROCESSOR_POWER_POLICY
        {
            public uint Revision;
            public byte DynamicThrottle;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
            public byte[] Spare;
            public uint Reserved;
            public uint PolicyCount;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
            public PROCESSOR_POWER_POLICY_INFO[] Policy;
        }

        struct MACHINE_PROCESSOR_POWER_POLICY
        {
            public uint Revision;                   // ULONG
            public PROCESSOR_POWER_POLICY ProcessorPolicyAc;
            public PROCESSOR_POWER_POLICY ProcessorPolicyDc;
        }


        [DllImport("powrprof.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool ReadProcessorPwrScheme(uint uiID, out MACHINE_PROCESSOR_POWER_POLICY pMachineProcessorPowerPolicy);
        public void ReadProcessorPowerScheme()
        {
            MACHINE_PROCESSOR_POWER_POLICY machinep = new MACHINE_PROCESSOR_POWER_POLICY();
            uint scheme = 0;

            if (ReadProcessorPwrScheme(scheme, out machinep))
            {

                //Then loop through machinep.ProcessorPolicyAc.Policy[]; array
                //Use:  PROCESSOR_POWER_POLICY_INFO processorPolicyInfoAc = mppp.ProcessorPolicyAc.Policy[i];
                //Use: processorPolicyInfoAc.DemotePercent;
                //Use: processorPolicyInfoAc.PromotePercent;

                //And don't forget to do the same for Dc (Dc is battery)
            }
        }
```

Edgar Rocha Carvalho

Answer (score 0):

use

```
PowerReadACValueIndex()/PowerReadDCValueIndex()
```

1. 1st parameter is `NULL`
2. 2nd parameter -- `GUID` for desired power scheme (`GUID_MAX_POWER_SAVINGS`/`GUID_MIN_POWER_SAVINGS`/`GUID_TYPICAL_POWER_SAVINGS`)
3. 3rd parameter -- `GUID_PROCESSOR_SETTINGS_SUBGROUP`
4. 4th parameter -- `GUID_PROCESSOR_THROTTLE_MAXIMUM` or `GUID_PROCESSOR_THROTTLE_MINIMUM`
5. 5th parameter is value receiver.

all the `GUID` description could be found in **winnt.h**